# I read a paperback novel in/around 1970: protagonists were an underground/partisans in a war by telepathy

Tags: story-identification, novel, warfare, good-against-evil, telepathy

It made a great impression on me at the time.  It was probably a few years old when I read it, if I remember the condition of the binding correctly.  The scene/s that stick in my mind have the protagonists, who are in some sort of resistance movement, hiding out, and they need to keep on guard because the enemy comes at them by telepathy, but they fight back likewise.  I picture one such scene actually taking place in a cellar, with the camaraderie of the good fight and a home-front touch a fifteen year old could delight in.  There were rather well-drawn-out rules for how the good guys and the bad guys could operate telepathically, so the reader could tell the good from the bad as a morality theme, and it was not an impossible struggle, either.
Thanks.

Comment: More details? . . .

Comment: And now I've got [a Blue Öyster Cult song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veteran_of_the_Psychic_Wars "Veteran of the Psychic Wars") in my head. Which was, to my surprise, co-written by Michael Moorcock, so perhaps it's a lead.

Comment: I have a last resort, which is to ask my older brother, who always seems to remember the same tiny incidents from forty years ago that I do, but with whom I am otherwise at war.  In fact, I'm afraid that this book--reading it--was one of those pivotal moments where I realized I had to veer away from the family's, especially his, take on things.

Comment: And thanks, ATS, twice; as to the BOC song and Moorcock, my book's thematic premise, or at least what sticks with me, was that this was an ordinary world except that the instruments of force were telepathic--no reincarnations or magic, I don't think.  1984 with a twist, perhaps, as opposed to Buffy the Vampire Slayer, although the TV series gave me the same sort of consolation; sort of the power of the average misfit against a State/mafia/hidden-regime.  I cannot remember.

Answer (score 2):

It reminds me of "The chrysalids" by John Wyndham. Although it was more about persecution of the telepathic children than about a war.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up.  No, I think mine was urban.  Living in Maine I think I'd remember if mine had happened in Labrador, right up the coast a few miles.  Thanks, though.

Comment: I just read the first chapter on-line.  I would have remembered that, as my first taste of what I'll call critical Christian literature.  Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Star Rangers by Andre Norton - Book Cover 01] [image: The Last Planet by Andre Norton - Book Cover 01]

For what it's worth, here's a guess: [**Star Rangers**](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2945) by Andre Norton. Also published under the title ''[**The Last Planet**](http://andre-norton-books.com/archive/Titles_L/Last_Planet/Last_Planet.htm)''.

> A lone ship of the Stellar Patrol crash-lands on an out-of-the-way
> planet. Quickly scouting around, the crew find evidence of a long
> vanished hi-tech civilization in the Sealed Cities, along with nomadic
> hunter-gatherer level groups of humans. When the rangers enter one of
> the cities, they find it occupied by another group of refugees and
> ruled by the Acturian Cummi. A master telepath, bent on becoming the
> planet's sole ruler, Cummi is not above controlling other people's
> minds. Zinga, a member of the Zacathan race, along with the human
> Kartr, both higher-order telepaths themselves, end up in a fierce
> mental battle with Cummi. ~ *Edited from [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/Star-Rangers-Andre-Norton/product-reviews/0152794263/ref=cm_cr_dp_text?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=byRankDescending#R5L7BESUHNNMI)*

Note: You can read the book in its entirety [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/10.1125/Baen/0671318276/0671318276__19.htm) :-)

Comment: I was a total Andre Norton freak in junior high school, 1966-69.  This sounds very likely!

Comment: And it wouldn't have worked in this case to ask my next-elder brother because Andre Norton was my personal route, as it seemed at the time.

Comment: @Chris I do hope it's the book you've been looking for :-) If not, well, reply back (hopefully with more clues) and we'll get cracking!

Comment: I'm into chapter three, "Mutiny", and it's not like the Nortons I read long ago: no telepathic cats, at least so far.  I'm very impressed at how much she knows about military culture.  The clarity of presentation is very attractive.  And the social analysis, likewise.  I would say she is more optimistic than the book I'm trying to recall, which, as I said above, was rather Orwellian, end-of-the-world-because-people-are-just-no-good.  But that's based on a supposed memory of one little scene, in a cellar in a war, and yet the people in the cellar were good people, yet definitely trapped.

Comment: I'm tempted to say my book had a Mary Poppins tone, albeit in a setting where to be caught by the secret police or the mafia or whoever was The End.  The thing I remember--well, I tried to transplant this memory, perhaps, into the later Foundation books which recently turned out to not be there: there were two tribes of telepaths, on competing wavelengths but also with contrasting colorations: spiritual warfare.  One vast metaphor for the typical school experience of two main cliques: the success-track and everybody else: spiritually the mechanistic party-line versus intimations of immortality

Comment: @Chris Crap, I didn't expect the bad news this quickly :-) Hmm, time for some more digging. Meanwhile, could you add in those thoughts about the possible mood/feel of the scene into your original post (keeping the current text intact)? Might come in handy!

Comment: I just finished it.  I'm a bit elated but I don't think I could have forgotten that all.

Comment: The main thing, the reason that scene in the cellar, or maybe around a fireplace in a dark cottage or room, stuck with me is it seemed so like my life at the time, that high school, Vietnam War, mother this, father that, was not a matter of statistics, grade point averages, vitamins, and megatons but was all part of a vital war fought with spirit and intention, and it was a battle of angels against demons, or human servants, I should say, of those opposing factions.  It was an "ah, hah" moment.  The only defense was a clean heart.  "How can you fight spirits?"  Why, you're one, too!

Comment: I just finished Star Rangers/The Last Planet.  I'm a bit elated but I don't think I could have forgotten that all.  It emboldens me to say, well, when I went to Iraq in 2004 I said to a retired (reserve) first sergeant that "nobody is going to mess with my Army or Constitution".  Now, nine years later, if I am the last believer in both institutions, I am still here, so the Army is still here and the Constitution.  I never met Norton's political writing in junior high, only her very comforting cat stories, but I wasn't seasoned enough for her real stuff, I'd say.  The forgotten book was enough.

Comment: I should add that this is all informing me that I was in a total fog in those years, as a math teacher told me when I was ten.  It seems the ensuing years took me even further into a fog.  "Grief is a fog," said Goethe, as I discovered in high school, but that's about all I learned in high school.

Comment: Let me repeat and emphasize that the crucial plot element, if we are to find this book, is that these guys in this cellar or darkened cottage were members of an underground resistance movement.

Comment: My first thought was John D. MacDonald's "Ballroom of the Skies", but I guess it doesn't really fit your description that well. It has alien telepaths apparently  waging a covert war on Earth, government secret police and a lone dissenter, but I don't recall any resistance movement as such.